# .NET SerialPort Multithreading

Tags: .net, multithreading, serial-port

Have device, getting data from it by SerialPort class.
Here is my method:

```
public WriteAndRead(){
    ...
    sp.Write(send_buffer.ToArray(), 0, send_buffer.Count);

    do
        {
            if (sp.BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                ret_val = sp.ReadByte();
                done = true;
            }
            else
                ret_val = -1;
        } while ((!done) && ((Environment.TickCount - char_tmo) < interchar_delay));
    ...
}
```

So i want to call it, from other threads.
Shall i wrap that part of code to **lock(sp){}**, to syncronize reading and writing. Or there is better solution how can i avoid situation, when one thread is writing, and other reading from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, locking is required.  The Write() calls are serialized just fine, taken care of by locking inside the device driver.  But there are non-zero odds that another thread races ahead of the one that called sp.Write() first and steals that thread's response.  Those odds are very small, which makes it such a very hard problem to diagnose when it *does* race.  You'll never reproduce it when testing, this goes wrong may once a week.

No, there is no simple better solution.  Leaving *all* the device communication up to only one thread is an alternative but you'll have to solve the asynchronicity problem for each individual thread.

You do need to fix the code, you cannot rely on the device responding within "interchar_delay".  Delays are much larger than that, the entire send_buffer needs to be transmitted and received by the device and processed.  Your own code could easily be subjected to arbitrary long delays by the garbage collector and the operating system swapping out pages of your process when the machine gets heavily loaded.  Disaster strikes when that happens just after the Write() call.  Never consider making the timeout less than 10 seconds.  Which is fine, it is supposed to be exceptional.  Do very strongly favor using the SerialPort.ReadTimeout property instead, it is implemented by the driver, it doesn't suffer from those arbitrarily long delays.

Comment: Thanks. I don't use ReadTimeout because it will throw exception, and i don't use try/catch, because i have many reads, and try/catch will take much time. Am i wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong.  The only reason it could possible throw so much that it will affect your program is when you use the wrong timeout.  Which is what I explained at length.  A timeout should always be exceptional.  If it is not then you'll have a very hard time making your program reliable.  It isn't actually that slow anyway, ~60 microseconds is still much faster than typical serial port traffic.

Comment: So, i must write just: while (!done) and set ReadTimeout=10sec, and wrap it to try/catch?

Comment: Just call ReadByte() inside a try/catch block, eliminate the loop and the test on BytesToRead.  Proper code is often smaller code :)

Answer (score 1):

Lock does the job. While one uses the port another is waiting. Unless you will use a separate port for each thread or sort of ports pool.